# redirect после авторизации в SPA

Tags: javascript, redirect, spa, аутентификация

При авторизации пользователь запускает метод `login` экземпляра класса `Auth` с параметрами, которые передает сервер: token, userId

Подскажите, каким образом можно перенаправить сразу на дефолтную страницу, которая доступна
авторизованным пользователям - `/home`

***App.js***

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit-element'
import {useRoutes} from './routes'
import {Auth} from './helpers/auth'

const isAuth= !!Auth.token
const route = useRoutes(isAuth)


class App extends LitElement {

    render() {
        return html`
            ${ route }
        `
    }
}
customElements.define('my-app', App)
```

***Routers.js***

```
import {Router} from '@vaadin/router'; 

const useRoutes = (isAuthenticated) => {
    const outlet = document.createElement('div')
    const router = new Router(outlet);

    if( isAuthenticated ) {
        router.setRoutes([
            {path: '/home', component: 'home-view'},
            {path: '/photo', component: 'photo-view'},
            {path: '/user', component: 'user-view'},
            {path: '/data', component: 'data-view'},
            {path: '(.*)', redirect: '/home'}
        ])
    } else {
        router.setRoutes([
            {path: '/login', component: 'login-page', action: async () => await import('./components/authentication/login')},
            {path: '/register', component: 'register-page', action: async () => await import('./components/authentication/register')},
            {path: '(.*)', redirect: '/login'}
        ])
    }

    return outlet
}


export {useRoutes}
```

***Auth.js***

```
class useAuth {
    constructor() {
        this.storageName = 'userData'

        this.token = null;
        this.userID = null;

        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.storageName))

        data && data.token
            ? this.login(data.token, data.userID)
            : null
    }

    login(jwtToken, id) {
        this.token = jwtToken
        this.userID = id

        localStorage.setItem(this.storageName, JSON.stringify({
            token: jwtToken,
            userID: id
        }))
    }
    logout() {
        this.token = null
        this.userID = null

        localStorage.removeItem(this.storageName)
    }
}

export const Auth = new useAuth()
```

Comment: Router.push (url)

Comment: @Дмытрык нет такого метода у vaadin-router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не найдя более интересного способа, решил просто создать функцию `redirect`

```
export const redirect = (url) => window.location.href = url
```